# How do I log out of a database, or switch user accounts, in FileMaker Pro 19?

Tags: filemaker

I am creating user accounts for a database I have inherited, which is hosted on my institution's FileMaker Server. I want to test these user accounts to confirm they are working as expected, with the correct privileges, before I send the credentials to the end users.

When I opened the database in my FileMaker client for the first time today, I was prompted to log in. Now, even if I close and reopen the database, or even the entire FileMaker application, I am automatically logged in, rather than re-prompted.

I can't find any menu item to log out or switch the active account. How can I log out or switch accounts so that I can test the other user accounts?

Answer (score 3):

You can block the automatic login by holding down the Shift key (Windows) or the Option key (macOS) when opening the file. You can disable it altogether in File > File Options… > Open.

You can also use the Re-Login script step to change users without closing the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the File Options (File > File Options on macOs), to see if the check "Allow stored credentials for authentication" is active